# Image POST php slug

Tags: php, image, post, slug, slugify

I'm trying to make a slug name to image while upload, i was testing with `str_replace` but it doesn't work.

```
$_FILES['imgProfile']['name'] = str_replace("í", "i", $_FILES['imgProfile']['name']);
```

it returns something like: `i?magen.png` and doesn't upload the image.

I tried with this function and works, but removes the file extension.

```
function slugify($text)
{
  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

  // transliterate
  $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');

  // remove duplicate -
  $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);

  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);

  if (empty($text)) {
    return 'n-a';
  }

  return $text;
}
```

I only need to remove `blank spaces` with `-`and characters like `á,é,í,ó,ú` with `a,e,i,o,u`

If the file name is: `"prueba para Guardar ímagen ñueva.png"`

it must be: `"prueba-para-guardar-imagen-nueva.png"`

Thanks!

Comment: did you look into str_replace?

Comment: yes, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your desired behavior you need to add to first row `\.`

```
// replace non letter or digits by -
$text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d\.]+~u', '-', $text);
```

and for third row too `\.`

```
// remove unwanted characters
$text = preg_replace('~[^-\w\.]+~', '', $text);
```

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you very much!!
Original: `prueba para Guardar ímagen ñueva.png`
Result: `prueba-para-guardar-i-magen-n-ueva.png`

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help:-)